# How to remove call logs from android programmatically?

Tags: android, calllog

how to delete/remove call log from application. I am doing like this

```
 this.getContentResolver().delete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null,null);
```

it not working.

Comment: make sure u have        `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />` permission in manifest

Comment: which error do u get? please post your logcat.

Comment: @imrankhan it working but i want to delete particular number from call logs.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Make sure u have following permissions in `Manifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

For deleting call logs for particular number try this way:

```
public void DeleteCallLogByNumber(String number) {   
    String queryString = "NUMBER=" + number; 
    this.getContentResolver().delete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, queryString, null);  
}
```

Comment: don't you mean  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />`? :)

Answer (score 12):

The existing solution will not delete numbers with 0 or + prefix.
For this to work for all phone numbers, one needs to put the number in single quotes, like so:

```
String queryString = "NUMBER='"+numberToDelete+"'";
context.getContentResolver().delete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, queryString, null);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 10):

Accepted answer will delete all calls from call log for a specific number. If you want to delete a only single call you can do it by passing CallLogId to that function and run this query.

```
public void DeleteCallById(String idd) {   
    this.getContentResolver().delete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,CallLog.Calls._ID + " = ? ",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(idd) });
    }
```

Comment: Thank You. Your answer was very helpful, simple, and providing of insight into the topic

Comment: how to get Call Log ID for last call ?

Answer (score 5):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"/>
```

You need to give only this permission to work along with this method:

```
this.getContentResolver().delete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null);
```

Its working perfectly for me. I've tested it on my Moto-G running
    Kitkat 4.4.2 and Samsung Note with Jelly Bean 4.1.

Comment: This works on Marshmallow too. I just added this comment if someone stumbles on this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an improved way, for example if the stored number in database is like:"914111222" this method can deal with numbers like:"+98 914 111 2222":

```
public void removeContactsLogFromPhoneLogs(String numberTag){
    char[] number=numberTag.toCharArray();
    String n="%";
    for(int i=0;i<number.length;i++)
    {
        n=n+(number[i]+"%");
    }
    String queryString=CallLog.Calls.NUMBER+" LIKE '"+n+"'"; 
    mContext.getContentResolver().delete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,queryString,null);

}
```

it requires permission as:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"/>
```

Comment: Using this method will delete other numbers... not all numbers are 914111222 some could be *2080 or 911. this will delete every number that contains 2080.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete multiple call log by specific ids you can use the method below:

```
public void deleteCallLog(List<String> listOfIds){
    getContentResolver().delete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,CallLog.Calls._ID + " in (" + TextUtils.join(",", listOfIds) + ")",
            null);
    callLogAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```